# CORBA sequences: can I define sequences of objects w/ methods?

Tags: java, rpc, sequence, idl, corba

I have an interface with a method that should return a list of items, and each item should have certain methods associated with it.  For example, I want to define a method listAllItems() that returns a bunch of "item" objects which have methods attached to them (so I can have the client process pick one of the items and say itemone.buy() for example, which would execute the corresponding method on the server).

Can I do this in CORBA?  It seems I can't define "interface Item" and then in some other interface say "sequence".

I'll be compiling my idl to Java, if it makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The information Peyton needed, the concept mapping between an IDL sequence and a Java set type, can be found on physical page 42, indexed page 23, of this manual:

http://www.omg.org/spec/I2JAV/1.3/

And to answer his question: apparently, java doesn't actually specify a sequence object even if you typedef. You are of course welcome to do so manually. But if you want to rely on what's done for you automatically by idlj, you're going to have to use the methods in <ObjectType>Helper.java. Those work with simple arrays of the type <ObjectType>[], and include getters and setters.

In brief: If your idl contained

```
struct MyObject
{
  long my_int;
};
typedef sequence<MyObject> MyObjects;
interface HasArray
{
  attribute MyObjects some_stuff;
};
```

Then your java implementation would need:

```
public class HasArrayImpl extends HasArrayPOA
{
  private List<MyObject> local_storage;

  /** getter */
  MyObject[] some_stuff()
  {
    /* ... */
  }

  /** setter */
  void some_stuff(MyObject[] newSome_stuff)
  {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

And under the hood, Java would create MyObjectsHelper and MyObjectsHolder for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

You'll have to give more details on why you say it isn't working for you. But I regularly work with IDL that contains a sequence of interfaces.